# Seifert Van Kampen Theorem and the amalgamated Product

Tags: abstract-algebra, general-topology, algebraic-topology, fundamental-groups

Say I have a reduced word of the form $\alpha * \beta \in \pi_1(A) *_{\pi_1(A \cap B) }\pi_1(B)$ , where $\alpha \in \pi_1(A)$ and $\beta \in \pi_1(B)$.

Now what is the multiplication of $\alpha*\beta$ supposed to represent ? Is it the concatenation of $\alpha$ and $\beta$ ?

Note: I am not asking for the technical details of the definition of an almagamated product, I think I understand it. I am asking for the interpretation of $*$ in this particular context (if there exists one).

Comment: Do you mean, given loop classes $a,b$ in $A$ and $B$, what loop does the loop class $a\ast b$ represent in $A\cup B$?

Comment: Yes, this is what I meant.

Comment: I recommend you edit the question to make it clearer. Maybe explore a simple example

Comment: Do you know that not all the elements of the amalgamated product have that form $\alpha *\beta$? There are others such as $\alpha_1*\beta_1*\alpha_2*\beta_2\cdots*\alpha_n* \beta_n$? But, yes at the level of elements the $*$ denotes the usual concatenation of loops. I think the asterisk can be omitted between the elements, but please wait for others opinions. It's been a while since I read a book on fundamental groups :-)

Comment: Yes, you don't write the multiplication sign (at least I've never seen it), I put it there to emphasise what its interpretation should be. Thank you for your answer though

Comment: Have you read the proof of the Seifert Van Kampen Theorem, which is where the representation of this product is described? Is there anything specific in that proof which you have trouble understanding?